# javascript/ionic - Google Maps not removing directions

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
directionDisplay.setMap(null);
```

is not working at my situation.

Working in ionic/corodova environment, Xcode ios project.

The app is the same concept of Uber.

An app needs to pull data from the database every 3 seconds to check if there is new order. If there is new order it gets location of an order and location of a driver.

Then puts the markers and shows directions between them.

There is an interval that watches if the order have been completed, once it is completed it should remove the directions and markers. Markers are removed but the directions are staying on the map.

The code is very long and StackOverFlow not letting me insert it here.

The console says that it cant find variable, that is strange since the variable is there.

Let me know where else I can share the code to show.

Comment: We can't really help much without getting any code to see. By the way instead of checking every 3 seconds the database, check `firebase` by google, it has realtime database, so you won't need to query the database every 3 seconds.

Comment: @mXX thanks a lot for suggestion, will look into it. I have fixed the problem with the code below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This code fixed the problem:

```
var gmarkers = [];// opening array

function removeMarkers(){ // creating function to remove everything on the map including the markers and directions
for(i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++){
gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
}
}

... other code is here

//inserting near the variable directionDisplay the code to push it into array
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

         gmarkers.push(directionsDisplay);
```